# Drag'n'drop bug in Qt 5.5 with USB touchscreen?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm

I'm trying to use drag'n'drop in a QTableView with a custom QAbstractTableModel in a linux Qt application, but there is a problem. I tracked it down to a minimalistic example which works with a QTableWidget, as there's the same problem and it's easier to reproduce.
When I start dragging a cell of the QTableWidget, normally the content of the dragged cell should be drawn sticked to the mouse cursor. On my Windows machine, this works like a charm *(see image 1*, sorry for the poor quality, but I had to use my camera, because otherwise I couldn't keep the drag).

If I run exactly the same code on my embedded system (ARM) with a touchscreen connected, the content of the dragged cell **isn't* drawn sticked to the cursor, but instead in the upper left corner of the screen (only one 'half' is visible, the other half is out of the viewport, *see image 2*).

Windows:
[image]

Embedded System with Touch (no visible mouse cursor):
[image]

**uname -a** on my embedded system:
Linux fsimx6 3.0.35-F+S #3 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 4 15:41:19 CEST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

**Qt version**: 5.5.0

**How to reproduce:**
Put a QTableWidget to your application, make sure showDropIndicator, dragEnabled and dragDropOverwriteMode are set to true, dragDropMode is set to DragDrop and defaultDropAction is set to MoveAction.

---

I've just found out (while writing this post) that it works also on my embedded system, when I connect a USB mouse instead of using the USB touchscreen. The difference is that there's a mouse cursor displayed in the application when using the USB mouse. With the touchscreen connected (eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3000-0408-35.00.00) the cursor automatically isn't drawn (decision of Qt?).
I see the correct x/y-positions when I output the event.pos() from the dragMoveEvent() method with touchscreen connect, so maybe there's some kind of connection between the cursor symbol and the blue content box?

Comment: Can you plug the USB touchscreen into your Windows box, and if so, do you get the same behavior as on ARM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just speculating here, but it seems like the implementation of dragging is tied to a mouse / cursor. Since touch does not have a cursor, there is no cursor for the dragged element to follow while dragging, thus it is stuck to 0x0. The issue might be with the rudimentary touch support for widgets or in your platform plugin, although I suspect the former. Test with the touchscreen under windows to verify that.

If there is a hidden cursor at 0x0, you could try to manually tie it to the touch position, and hope that will do the trick. For example [creating mouse events that follow the drag position as you drag and post them into the application event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936714/qt5-5-how-to-override-mousepress-event-coordinates-at-application-level/32937134#32937134).

If that doesn't work, you could implement your own drag and drop mechanism that works with touch. It may turn to be quite tedious for widgets, I've done custom drag and drop in QML and it was fairly trivial.

Also, you could try to see if dragging will work correctly in QML, which is newer and more touch centered. The old QtWidgets module is pretty much a done deal and isn't really designed with touch in mind. QML is quite easy and fast to work with, so I'd recommend using that unless you need the extra functionality of the old widgets which is still not fully implemented in the QML widget analogs from QtQuick Controls.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer gave me the right hint. In the dragMoveEvent I've logged the cursor position: `qDebug() << "Cursor: " << QCursor::pos();` which always resulted in (0/0). So I tried to set the cursor position manually in `dragMoveEvent` by adding `QCursor::setPos(mapToGlobal(event->pos()));` and now it works! :-)

Comment: You got off easy :) Qt design limitations are often difficult to get around.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's actually a bigger project, so it'd be hard to port it to QML. I have to support dragndrop between ListViews and TableViews, where the TableItems have different spans.. It was a hard time to get it to work. Next project will be realized with QML ;)